# How to populate a column in SQL by comparing values from one table against another

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have two tables:

**Vacation_days**:

```
id    name     work_days    tier
--------------------------------
 1    John        366       Null
 2    Mike        764       Null
 3    Josh       1163       Null
```

**Vacation_algorithm**:

```
day1     day2        tier
-------------------------
    0        184      1
  185        364      2
  365       5999      3
 6000    1000000      4
```

I want to iterate through each row in the vacation_days table and see what tier the work_days in the vacation_days corresponds with (work_days must lie in between start_day and end_day).

Then I want to place that tier number in the tier column contained in vacation_days which is currently filled with null values.

I have tried this:

```
Select tier 
From Vacation_Algorithm 
Where (Select work_days 
       From vacation_days 
       Where work_days = 366) between day1 and day2.
```

This returns the correct output, which is a column with tier 3. However, I want a formula to do this with all the rows in my Vacation_days table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use a `join`.  I would choose a `left join`, so no rows get left behind if none match:

```
select vd.*, va.tier
from vacation_days vd left join
     vacation_algorithm va
     on vd.work_days between va.day1 and va.day2;
```

Comment: Thanks this worked! To update the tier column in vacation_days using the tiers populated from vacation_algorithm could you do this: Update vacation_days set vacation_days.tier=(select va.tier from vacation_days vd left join vacation_algorithm va on vd.work_days between va.day1 and va.day2);